# How to place a label before an input box using css?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have this html:

```
<div class="entry-content">
<div class="job_listings" data-location="" data- 
keywords="" data-show_filters="true" data- 
show_pagination="false" data-per_page="10" data- 
orderby="featured" data-order="DESC" data-categories="" 
>
<form class="job_filters">
<div class="search_jobs">
<div class="search_keywords">
<label for="search_keywords">Keywords</label>
<input type="text" name="search_keywords" 
id="search_keywords" placeholder="Keywords" value="" 
/>
</div>
<div class="search_location">
<label for="search_location">Location</label>
<input type="text" name="search_location" 
id="search_location" placeholder="Location" value="" />
</div>
```

I want to place the label `Where?` before `location` and `What?` before `keywords` using css.

Tried:

```
label[What?]:before {
  content: "search_location";
  color: green; 
}
```

Didn't work.

At the moment the label `location` listed in my html shows up as a placeholder, not a label- likewise for  the label `search keywords` This is fine but i would like those placeholders replacing with, for `location` `London, Berlin, Bristol...` and for `search keywords` `Chef, Cleaner, Manager...`

It's perhaps clearer if you view at: https://adsler.co.uk/jobs/

Comment: This a bit broad. Can you change the HTML? If so, then just type "What?" and "Where?" in the appropriate places. Otherwise, have you tried `label[for='search_keywords']::before` for a selector?

Comment: Yes, tried that. Not able to edit html as it's a wp plugin so written in php, html, javascript

Comment: plz try something to check the problem just  label::before{content:"what";} to see if it works on all labels

Comment: On your live site, the labels don't show because they have `display: none` in frontend.css. So make them visible first. Or, forget the labels and add the ::before to the container divs instead (the .search_keywords and .search_location ones).

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just place the label with html? Like this

```html
    <div class="entry-content">
    <div class="job_listings" data-location="" data-
    keywords="" data-show_filters="true" data-
    show_pagination="false" data-per_page="10" data-
    orderby="featured" data-order="DESC" data-categories=""
    >
    <form class="job_filters">
    <div class="search_jobs">
    <div class="search_keywords">
    <label style="color: green;">What?</label>
    <label for="search_keywords">Keywords</label>
    <input type="text" name="search_keywords"
    id="search_keywords" placeholder="Keywords" value=""
    />
    </div>
    <div class="search_location">
    <label style="color: green;">Where?</label>
    <label for="search_location">Location</label>
    <input type="text" name="search_location"
    id="search_location" placeholder="Location" value="" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Too difficult. It's a Wp plugin so written in php, html, javascript

Comment: Tried that. Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the HTML snippet you've provided, your CSS selector `label[What?]:before` is not going to resolve to anything. Square brackets `[]` are used to select elements based on one of their attributes (see [attribute selector definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)). You appear to be trying to pass in a desired value (which doesn't exist yet) as an attribute selector, which is impossible.

Looking at the site, the other trouble you're having is that the labels themselves have been hidden. This is currently in your CSS, so will need to be changed or otherwise overridden:

```css
.job_filters .search_jobs div label {
  display: none;
}
```

Then, as already suggested by Mr Lister, something like this will get you on the right track. I've tested in the browser on your site and it works once the labels have been unhidden:

```css
label[for="search_location"]:before {
  content: "Where?";
}

label[for="search_keywords"]:before {
  content: "What?";
}
```

I'm going to assume that your actual intention is for the labels to display but you want to change their existing values from "Keywords" and "Location" using only CSS? It's not achievable. You could use a bit of JavaScript to change the text content, but not by CSS with your current implementation.